# Unit test promise $q call

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

```
$scope.load = function() {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    myService.send('SomeRequestMessage');

    deferred.promise.then(function(data) {
        var modalPopup = loadModal.open('TITLE', data);

        modalPoupup.result.then(function(action) {
            if(angular.isDefined(action.dirName)) {
               myService.sendReq(action.dirName);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I have unit test for above function as follows,

```
describe('my tests, ', function () {
    var deferred;
    var lRootScope;
    var lmodalInstance;

    beforeEach(inject(function($q, $rootScope) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        lRootScope = $rootScope;
        lmodalInstance = sinon.stub( { open: function() {}, close: function() {} } );
        lmodalInstance.open.returns({ result: deferred.promise});
    }));

    xit('should call the popup open method once when the open button is pressed.', function () {

        var callBack =sinon.stub();           
        scope.load();           
        expect(lModalInstance.open.calledOnce).toBe(true);
    });
```

This test fails and throws `"Expected false to be true."`

May be below line of code executes and immediately the unit test expect method validates without validating promise (not sure).

```
myService.send('SomeRequestMessage');
```

Please help to fix this test.

Comment: what is send ( `myService.send('SomeRequestMessage');` ) function?? callback or promise?

Comment: The `$scope.load` function is buggy. The promise created is never resolved.  That is why the unit test fails.

Comment: @georgeawg  I have edited `$scope.load` function. is this what you meant?